# Read the value of input returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have this input

```
 <input id="look" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" max="100000" class="form-control" name="number" required>
```

and I want to read the value that user will put at that time. So I wrote

```
$(function() {
    $('#look').on('keyup', function(e) {
        var temp2 = $('look').val();
        alert(temp2);

    });
});
```

and when the user starts typing the value inside the alert is undefined..

Comment: `$('look')` matches `<look>` elements.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem was caused by a typo.

Comment: for match _id_ use _#_ before name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be `#look` rather than `look`, but rather than a selector use `$( this )`

```
$(function() {
    $('#look').on('keyup', function(e) {
        var temp2 = $(this).val(); //look should have been #look
        alert(temp2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#look').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var temp2 = $('#look').val();  // you are missing #
  alert(temp2);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(function() {
    $('#look').on('keyup', function(e) {
        var temp2 = $('#look').val(); //# is used for id selectors
        alert(temp2);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

while you are getting value from the input field, you missed "#" before ID.

replace 
       var temp2 = $('look').val();
 with 
       var temp2 = $('#look').val(); 
or you can use $(this).val()